# Problem with adding Excel files at Pandas | wrapper return func

Tags: python

Hi everybody I have a problem uploading a excel file with Pandas
I have taken the file in archive, if I uploaded it directly it gaves me an error. If I cope and paste the excel file there is no problem.

The code is very easy:

```
data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\obett\Desktop\Corporate Governance\pandas.xlsx")
```

and this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/obett/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\obett\Desktop\Corporate Governance\Aida_Export_67.xlsx")
  File "C:\Users\obett\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\obett\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 344, in read_excel
    data = io.parse(
  File "C:\Users\obett\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1170, in parse
    return self._reader.parse(
  File "C:\Users\obett\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 492, in parse
    data = self.get_sheet_data(sheet, convert_float)
  File "C:\Users\obett\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 549, in get_sheet_data
    converted_row = [self._convert_cell(cell, convert_float) for cell in row]
  File "C:\Users\obett\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 549, in <listcomp>
    converted_row = [self._convert_cell(cell, convert_float) for cell in row]
  File "C:\Users\obett\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 514, in _convert_cell
    elif cell.is_date:
  File "C:\Users\obett\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\read_only.py", line 101, in is_date
    return Cell.is_date.__get__(self)
  File "C:\Users\obett\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 256, in is_date
    self.data_type == 'n' and is_date_format(self.number_format)
  File "C:\Users\obett\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\read_only.py", line 66, in number_format
    _id = self.style_array.numFmtId
  File "C:\Users\obett\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\read_only.py", line 56, in style_array
    return self.parent.parent._cell_styles[self._style_id]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Could you please include a code snippet of your code where the error is so we can understand it?

Comment: I did it now, I thought it was irrelevant because it was a simple one, thanks

Comment: What do you mean by copy and paste? Do you copy the file itself? Do you open it, copy its contents, and paste that into a new spreadsheet? Something else?

Comment: I open it, copy all the contents in the exact same order and past into in a new empty excel file, in this case it works. But I would like to loading it directly